# How do I translate Dmsg out put after Ubuntu 14.04 installation, as below?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

Dmsg.txt:

```
[  676.628722] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1267 at /build/buildd/linux-3.13.0/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:4195    intel_modeset_check_state+0x73c/0x750 [i915]()
[  676.628726] wrong connector dpms state
[  676.628728] Modules linked in: cuse snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_codec_hdmi hid_generic gpio_ich dell_wmi sparse_keymap bnep rfcomm dell_laptop dcdbas usbhid hid snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_page_alloc snd_seq_midi coretemp snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi joydev serio_raw snd_seq r852 sm_common snd_seq_device nand snd_timer nand_ecc nand_bch btusb snd bluetooth bch r592 wl(POX) i915 lpc_ich nand_ids memstick drm_kms_helper drm mtd cfg80211 soundcore shpchp mac_hid i2c_algo_bit wmi parport_pc video ppdev lp parport sdhci_pci firewire_ohci psmouse ahci firewire_core libahci crc_itu_t pata_acpi sdhci sky2
[  676.628809] CPU: 0 PID: 1267 Comm: Xorg Tainted: P        W  OX 3.13.0-49-generic #81-Ubuntu
[  676.628813] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Inspiron 1525                   /      , BIOS A17 10/27/2009
[  676.628816]  00000000 00000000 eb6b3b58 c1656658 eb6b3b98 eb6b3b88 c1056a7e f9b4ff36
[  676.628827]  eb6b3bb4 000004f3 f9b45b34 00001063 f9afdb6c f9afdb6c ec18ac00 ec189000
[  676.628838]  f68c9dc0 eb6b3ba0 c1056ad3 00000009 eb6b3b98 f9b4ff36 eb6b3bb4 eb6b3bf4
[  676.628848] Call Trace:
[  676.628859]  [<c1656658>] dump_stack+0x41/0x52
[  676.628867]  [<c1056a7e>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7e/0xa0
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? Translate in what language? Or do you want to know how to deal with the warning?

Comment: I'm a complete novice. So I can't translate anything the computer tells me. This just happened to be a small part the messages I got after upgrading to the latest version.   The language is English but I'm not familiar with the computer vocabulary. I have no idea what they machine is trying to warn me. Where do you and your colleagues get your experience to be able to understand what the computer is saying?  Is there a book out like Ubuntu for complete idiots or something like that?